# Show as expanded doesn't work

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

I am trying to make my own theme for drupal 8. but I am struggling with the menu.
my menu looks something like this

```
parent1
- child 1.1
- child 1.2
parent2
- child 2.1
- child 2.2
```

but only the parents are visible.

I used the menu.html.twig file from the classy theme.

edit:
I tried my theme on other site and there the children are displayed. so guess the problems was not because of theme. so i activated the stark theme, but also there I can't see my full menu tree. 
and the checkboxes show as expanded are checked

Comment: I used the `{ }` button to indent the menu example so that it displays as expected.

Comment: Your menu is a block and you render in the page?

Comment: Is your theme specifying 'classy' as the base theme?

Comment: Sorry, but did you set **Maximum number of menu levels to display** setting on the menu block settings form? Core menu blocks in D8 work like Menu Block blocks in D7.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your parent links are set to **Show as expanded** on the `/admin/structure/menu/manage/main` page